# Creating Electron window with variable for width and height results in no window, and no error

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to do something like this, and I get no window when I try this. What could I be overlooking?

The window works perfectly when I launch it using straight numerical width and height, but using a variable leads to it not rendering.

```
function createNewMainWindow() {
  var a = 1000;
  var b = 800;
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: true,
    width: a,
    height: b,
    minWidth: 300,
    minHeight: 300,
    frame: false,
    title: 'Recall',
    icon: iconPath,
    alwaysOnTop: false,
    useContentSize: false,
    webPreferences: {
      zoomFactor: 1,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }
  });
}

app.on('ready', async () => {
  await installExtensions();
  createNewMainWindow();
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/app.html`); 
  mainWindow.show();
  mainWindow.focus();
}
```

Comment: Do you have `mainWindow` declared somewhere? I'm not sure if that relates to your problem, but it's not clear how the `ready` handler and `createNewMainWindow` would be referencing the same value.

Comment: I suspect you're omitting an important detail here; there's no way that the the `BrowserWindow` constructor would "know" whether the height and width were specified via literals or variable values. Maybe in simplifying your post, you're leaving out the actual problem. Like maybe it's not a simple `a` and `b` variable but a situation where your variables are undefined.

Comment: I have modified my code such that I'm defining the variables exactly as shown, hardcoded just before the function call, so it seems not likely to be the case.

I have excluded other code, however the entire thing works when I use numbers, and fails when I use variables so it seems very likely I am overlooking something within my limited code sample.

Comment: That really should not be possible; a value is a value. Are you doing code transpilation? Sometimes that can explain bizarre behaviors; posting the transpiler output would be helpful if that's the case. Otherwise, I can't help but suspect you're actually doing something more complicated than `a` and `b`.

Comment: I am, unfortunately, literally using the code exactly as shown above now following my earlier edit. There is nothing more complicated going on within the context of this part of my application. 

It is  being transpiled, but I can't possibly find the relevant part of the file. That being said, I've never run into any issue like this related to transpiling.

Comment: Try declaring `mainWindow` in the outer scope; It's not hard to imagine the transpiler for that async function having difficulties with an undeclared variable.

Comment: Removing async and await, I was able to at least start getting some error messages. I don't quite know what the issue was, I was a bit too focused on fixing it, but in any event, being able to see error messages got me up and running.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your mainwindow.loadURL() function is being called before it is declared inside your createNewMainWindow() function. You could try this...

```
function createNewMainWindow() {
var a = 1000;
var b = 800;
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: true,
    width: a,
    height: b,
    minWidth: 300,
    minHeight: 300,
    frame: false,
    title: 'Recall',
    icon: iconPath,
    alwaysOnTop: false,
    useContentSize: false,
    webPreferences: {
      zoomFactor: 1,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/app.html`);

  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.show();
    mainWindow.focus();
  });

}

app.on('ready', async () => {
  await installExtensions();
  createNewMainWindow();
}
```